# Restore SQL Database Fail - Access Denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

A colleague of mine is joining me in the development of a project with a SQL database. He cloned the code, rebuilt the project updating the dependencies and now just needs the SQL database locally to begin developing. He installed SQL Server Express v17.4 to match mine. Using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) I performed a Backup and passed it to him and he performed a Restore. However on running SSMS he gets the following error:

```
Restore of database failed.
The operating system returned an error '5(Access Denied)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation'
```

When restoring the database in SSMS we did click on Files and check the box 'Relocate all files to folder' and specify his User folder. We then tried restoring to the default location and this time it did restore but the Visual Studio project couldn't access the database. When we used SQL Server Object Explorer to check the database there were no tables listed.

The database connection string is as follows (Database name replaced):

```
"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Can anyone suggest how we provide SQL with access to the database or the directory where it is located please?

Comment: Is LocalDB running in the same user or is it shared from a different user?

Comment: Can you expand a little please, I don't quite follow? I have installed MS SQL Server Express, with LocalDb, on my standalone PC. My colleague is at a separate location, not networked running his own SQL Server Express with LocalDb on his PC.

Comment: Your colleague's installation of LocalDB, is it set up for all users on the machine, or only for his user account? Does a file exist already in the target location (it won't overwrite)? ARe you sure he has access to the target location?